# Number of holes in 1-Dimensional Skeleton of Tetrahedron.

Tags: algebraic-topology, laplacian

Suppose I have the following 1-dimensional skeleton of a tetrahedron:

[image]

I assumed that it would have 4 1-dimensional holes but it turns out that the $1^{st}$ Betti number is 3.

i.e. the nullity of the 1-combinatorial Laplacian is 3.

[image]

However, I don't see why this is the case. Shouldn't the holes be where the faces should be? Can someone care to explain?

Comment: i don't know if you're asking for an intuitive visual answer, but if you imagine all vertices in one plane, e.g. with 3 at the center of the 0-1-2-triangle, then you can clearly see three holes.

Comment: why do you view in a plane and not in 3 dimensional space? Sorry i find the definition of holes hard to understand. Intuitively, i view holes as areas where you cannot shrink the cycle down to a point.

Comment: the answer to your "why" question is "because that's how the math works". a figure 8 is counted as having two holes, even though if you thicken the crossing point a bit you can see a third loop as running along the outer boundary of the figure.

Comment: another remark that might be helpful is that only the "number of holes" is an invariant, not the specific individual holes. if you deform the figure in another way you might count different loops as holes, but will still end up with a count of three.

Answer (score 2):

There is a relation linking these cycles. Namely,
\begin{align*}\partial [0,1,3]+\partial[1,2,3]=&[1,3]-[0,3]+[0,1]+[2,3]-[1,3]+[1,2]\\
=&[0,1]+[2,3]+[1,2]\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}\partial[0,1,2]+\partial[0,2,3]=&[1,2]-[0,2]+[0,1]+[2,3]-[0,3]+[0,2]\\
=&[0,1]+[2,3]+[1,2].\end{align*}
Thus, the dimension is at most $4-1=3$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there are no 2 cycles in the complex above.

Comment: Indeed, here $\partial[0,1,3]$ is just a way to denote the $1$-cycle $[0,1]+[1,3]+[3,0]$.