# Relation between maximum value of 1st Betti number and number of faces

Tags: algebraic-topology, betti-numbers

Let $K$ be an abstract simplicial complex, where $\{0\}, \{1\}, \ldots, \{n-1\} \in K$, and $\{i,j\} \in K$ for $0 \leq i < j < n$ (indicating that the 1-skeleton forms a complete graph). It's important to note that $K$ has no 2-simplices. However, we should observe that the number of 2-faces in $K$ is given by $\binom{n}{2+1}$.

The number of 1-dimensional holes, represented by the Betti number $\beta_1$, must be upper-bounded by the number of 2-faces, as each 'hole' corresponds to a missing higher-order simplex that covers such a hole. Surprisingly, a post on [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245163/number-of-holes-in-1-dimensional-skeleton-of-tetrahedron) highlights a scenario where the number of 1-holes is strictly less than the number of 2-faces, as demonstrated in the case of the tetrahedron.

A quick simulation, considering the simplicial complex $K$ with $n = 2$ through $20$, reveals that $\beta_1$ is significantly smaller than $\binom{n}{2+1}$.

| Vertices of the simplicial complex | Number of 2-faces | Max value of the Betti number $\beta_1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 10 | 6 |
| 6 | 20 | 10 |
| 7 | 35 | 15 |
| 8 | 56 | 21 |
| 9 | 84 | 28 |
| 10 | 120 | 36 |
| 11 | 165 | 45 |
| 12 | 220 | 55 |
| 13 | 286 | 66 |
| 14 | 364 | 78 |
| 15 | 455 | 91 |
| 16 | 560 | 05 |
| 17 | 680 | 20 |
| 18 | 816 | 36 |
| 19 | 969 | 53 |
| 20 | 1140 | 71 |

What is the maximum value of $\beta_1$ for a simplicial complex with $n$ vertices? Can this formula be generalized to $\beta_k$ for any arbitrary $k$?

Comment: Yes, the skeleton of K is a complete graph

Comment: No other simplex is in K except for vertices and edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value of $\beta_1$ for a simplicial complex with $n$ vertices is $\binom{n}{2} - n + 1$. This is achieved with the complete graph on $n$ vertices, so we have the maximum $\binom{n}{2}$ edges and no $2$-faces. To compute the homology of this, collapse a spanning tree to a point. Since this tree is a nice contractible subspace, this does not change the homotopy type and hence doesn't change the homology. In a complete graph on $n$ vertices, a spanning tree will have $n-1$ edges: pick a vertex $v$ and add an edge from $v$ to each of the other $n-1$ vertices. Once this has been collapsed to a point, the resulting space is a bouquet of circles, one for each remaining edge. We started with $\binom{n}{2}$ edges and collapsed $n-1$ to a point, so we are left with $\binom{n}{2} - n + 1$ edges, and hence this many circles. So this is the first Betti number.

I didn't know the formula for $\max \beta_k$ for large values of $k$, but it should be achieved with the $k$-skeleton of an $(n-1)$-simplex. Some computations in SageMath:

```
sage: def max_betti(n, k): # n=vertices, k=dimension
....:     K = simplicial_complexes.Simplex(n-1)
....:     return K.n_skeleton(k).betti(k)
....: 
sage: [max_betti(n,2) for n in (1..15)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, 120, 165, 220, 286, 364]
sage: [max_betti(n,3) for n in (1..15)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 15, 35, 70, 126, 210, 330, 495, 715, 1001]
sage: [max_betti(n,4) for n in (1..15)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 21, 56, 126, 252, 462, 792, 1287, 2002]
```

The first of these seems to be https://oeis.org/A000292. The second is https://oeis.org/A000332. The third is https://oeis.org/A000389.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please leave a reference about the spanning tree collapse procedure?